# ACL structure to allow default permissions and 2nd set of permissions to over-ride the defaults

Tags: php, mysql, acl

I am hoping to get some ideas or help in implementing an ACL to set which users have the capability to **view**, **edit**, **create**, and **delete** in my PHP/MySQL application.

Below are the main core module/sections of my app which will all allow me to set a permission level for each user for each section to determine what they can and cannot do...

```
Projects (view | edit | Create | Delete)
Project Tasks (view | edit [edit includes task title, description] | Create | Delete)

Project Task Assigned User (edit)
Project Task Due Date  (edit)
Project Task Tags  (edit)
Project Task Milestone  (edit)

Project Tags (view | edit | Create | Delete)
Project Milestones (view | edit | Create | Delete)
Project KanBan Board (view)
Project Gantt Charts (view)
Project Wiki (view | edit | Create | Delete)
Project Stats (view | edit | Create | Delete)
Project Files (view | edit | Create | Delete)
```

**The setting page to set permissions on each user for each section will be like this image...**

[image]

---

**Which corresponds with a MySQL database record for each box something like this...**

[image]

---

Where I need help is setting it up so that by default when a new record in one of these section/module is created as well as new users created they will have some default permissions set.

For example by default all users will automatically have View permissions for all the modules.

Then on another page will be the settings to set a per user, per module permission which would then over-ride the default permissions.

So what I am not sure of is how to basically have 2 sets of permissions and combine them and allow the 2nd set to over-ride the first.

1st set are the default permissions for all users on all modules.  Perhaps all users by default can view all modules but cannot edit any modules or delete and records.

The 2nd set of permissions is where it overrides the 1st set on a per user, per module.  So if all users cannot delete records, then this set might allow 5 users ability to delete records.

I need help in the whole blending/merging of these 2 sets while allowing the over-ride to happen in PHP.

Any ideas how I could make that work?

The way I see it, the permission settings image shown below would exist on 2 pages.  1 page to handle the global/default permissions and the 2nd setting page would be where the permissions over-rides are set.

---

**My Theory for a solution/how it works**

I think it could have 2 PHP Arrays.

**Default Permissions Array** - has a key/value for every module/entity that we are setting permissing on.  The **Key** is the module name.  **Value** Is the Permissions for that module which applies to all users.

```
$defaultPermissionsArray = array(
    'project' => 'view',
    'project_task' => 'view',
    'project_milestones' => 'view',
    //... more module permissions
);
```

**User Permission Array** - Also has a key/value array with every module.  It then has a permissions value for the current logged in user which has the same **key** name as the default permissions array for that module and this value will over-ride the default permission for this user on that particular module.

```
// This user would have permission over-ride from default permissions allowing them to edit projects and milestones
$currentUserPermissionsArray = array(
    'project' => 'edit',
    'project_task' => 'view',
    'project_milestones' => 'edit',
    //... more module permissions
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have come up with a basic solution.  I had previously though that PHP's `array_merge()` added duplicate matching keys as a child array item.  NOw I see it actually works so posting my solution, maybe will help someone someday or myself.

I am still open to ideas for improvements.

```
$defaultPermissionsArray = array(
    'test' => 'view',
    'project' => 'view',
    'project_task' => 'view',
    'project_milestones' => 'view',
    //... more module permissions
);
$currentUserPermissionsArray = array(
    'project' => 'edit',
    'project_task' => 'view',
    'project_milestones' => 'edit',
    //... more module permissions
); 


$mergedPermissions = array_merge(
    $defaultPermissionsArray,
    $currentUserPermissionsArray
);
```

**Result**

User's Permissions merge with the core default permissions and over-ride the modules with the user's permissions for that section...

When app loads, the user only has **view** permissions for all modules.  After this code is ran, they gain **edit** permissions for 2 modules...

```
Array
(
    [test] => view
    [project] => edit
    [project_task] => view
    [project_milestones] => edit
)
```